# How to simplify multiple switch in PHP?

Tags: php, while-loop, switch-statement

is it possible to simplify this code? I am trying to put all cases in a switch but always d break in the first case and i need all echo's in the html. What is possible? Thank you!

```
$resultservices = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id_client = $id_client");

while($rowservice = mysqli_fetch_array($resultservices)){
    $php = (int)$rowservice['php'];
    $java = (int)$rowservice['java'];
    $ruby = (int)$rowservice['ruby'];
    $node = (int)$rowservice['node'];
}

// Values can be "1" or "0". Example: php:1, java:1, ruby:0, node:1

switch ($php) {
    case 0: break;
    case 1: echo "<li>php</li>"; break;
}

switch ($java) {
    case 0: break;
    case 1: echo "<li>java</li>"; break;
}

switch ($ruby) {
    case 0: break;
    case 1: echo "<li>ruby</li>"; break;
}

switch ($node) {
    case 0: break;
    case 1: echo "<li>node</li>"; break;
}
```

Comment: Would putting `case 0: break;` at the end of the switch statement not work?

Comment: If you put the service variables in an array, you could do a single switch (or even use the ternary operator) in a foreach loop

Comment: what is the difference between service01, service02, service04 sine all = (int)$rowservice['1'];

Comment: I made ​​a correction in the code, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I'm not sure what you're trying to do, how about:

```
$resultservices = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id_client = $id_client");

while($rowservice = mysqli_fetch_array($resultservices)){
    $service[1] = (int)$rowservice['1'];
    $service[2] = (int)$rowservice['1'];
    $service[3] = (int)$rowservice['0'];
    $service[4] = (int)$rowservice['1'];
}

foreach ($service as $k=>$v) {
    if ($v) {
        echo "<li>service".$k."</li>";
    }
}
```

[edit] I see we've got some new variables.

```
while($rowservice = mysqli_fetch_array($resultservices)){
    $service['php'] = (int)$rowservice['php'];
    $service['java'] = (int)$rowservice['java'];
    $service['ruby'] = (int)$rowservice['ruby'];
    $service['node'] = (int)$rowservice['node'];
}

foreach ($service as $k=>$v) {
    if ($v) {
        echo "<li>".$k."</li>";
    }
}
```

Although really, all you're doing is outputting the last row of your MySQL, so you could also do

```
    $resultservices = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id_client = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connecDB, $id_client)."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

    while($rowservice = mysqli_fetch_array($resultservices)){
        if ($rowservice['php']) {
            echo "<li>php</li>"
        }
        if ($rowservice['java']) {
            echo "<li>java</li>"
        }
        if ($rowservice['ruby']) {
            echo "<li>ruby</li>"
        }
        if ($rowservice['node']) {
            echo "<li>node</li>"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!, but how I can put different text on each li? In my example, I have a list with names and should show depending on the value

Answer (score 0):

Given that 3 of your four service values are going to have the SAME value, you could eliminate 2 of the switches and end up with the same results:

```
$service01 = (int)$rowservice['1'];
$service02 = (int)$rowservice['1']; // identical to service01
$service03 = (int)$rowservice['0'];
$service04 = (int)$rowservice['1']; // identical to service01
```

meaning you could have:

```
switch($service01) {
    case 0: break;
    case 1: echo "<li>service01, 02, and 04</li>"; break;
}
```

And then, assuming these values will never be anything but true/false 0/1 values, you could eliminate the switches entirely and go with a conventional `if`:

```
if ($service01) {
    echo "service 01, 02 and 04";
}
```